# Chosen não funciona com laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, modal, chosen

Estou tentando usar o [Bootstrap + Chosen](http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/) com laravel dentro de modal, mas simplesmente não funciona.
Fiz todos os imports e nada

Os imports fiz assim:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/chosen.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="{{ url('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="{{ url('js/chosen.jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

O que eu gostaria que acontecesse é mais ou menos como segue no código abaixo

```js
$('.btn-botao').on('click', function(){
   $('.modal').modal('show');
});


$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('select', this).chosen('destroy').chosen( {allow_single_deselect: true} );         
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-botao">Clique aqui</a>

<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="form-control" data-placeholder="Selecione">
          <option  value="0"></option>
          <option  value="1">Opção 1</option>
          <option  value="2">Opção 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help-me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os links de inclusão dos js no cabeçalho estão funcionando? Se sim tenta alterar o js. Tenta assim:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.myModal', function () {
    $('#meu_select').chosen('destroy').chosen( {allow_single_deselect: true} );       
})
```

Comment: Sim, porque em outra pagina onde nao uso modal, funciona

Comment: também não funcionou

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada melhor e reformular a resposta então.

Comment: Blz. Obrigado..

Comment: Descobri. Apenas mude o seu `show` para `shown`